# Retrieve JSON Data returned from WCF rest service

Tags: c#, jquery, json, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get values of attributes from JSON using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432196/how-to-get-values-of-attributes-from-json-using-jquery)

I have validated the `json` being return using jsonlint and it is valid. As a quick example,

`"JSONDataResult": "{ \"?xml\":{\"@version\":\"1.0\",\"@encoding\":\"utf-8\"},\"Root\":{\"Information\":{\"Error\":{\"ErrorNo\":\"0\",\"ErrorMsg\":null},\"Address\":{\"Address\":[{\"@AddressID\":\"1232233\",\"@Sequence\":\"1\",\"@Description\":\"Company, Building, 11 Street, County, City\"}`

...more data here and all the correct tags etc.

Using the following method returns the above data structure, but I can't break it into its components.

```
      $.getJSON('http://localhost/WcfRestService/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/mypostcode', 
       function (data) {
          //tried all sorts of variations of this sort of thing: data.Root.Information.Address.Address[0]
    });
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: When you pasted isn't valid JSON: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: You should probably provide more information about it.

Comment: I want to get the address out of each of the address fields.  No joy at the minute.

Comment: What is wrong with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432196/how-to-get-values-of-attributes-from-json-using-jquery) you accepted?

Comment: Now that the json is being returned via a wcf rest service rather than an http handler it just is not having it.

Comment: this line comes back undefined -- var addresses = json.Root.Information.Address.Address;

Answer (score 0):

I would try to find out what the recieved json structure really look like. Just debug *data* to the console or write an alert showing it to you. My guess is that you need to call:

`data.JSONDataResult.Root...`

or

`data.d.JSONDataResult.Root...`

to access the 'Root' property.